# Use the numbers 4 4 7 8 9 10 = 740

Tags: mathematics

I've got a puzzle to which I can't find the answer. Form the number $740$ using only these numbers:

$4$ $4$ $7$ $8$ $9$ $10$

And these operators:
$+$ $-$ $*$ $/$ $($ $)$

Comment: Is it necessary to use all of them? Are we allowed to concatenate digits (e.g., use two 4s to make 44)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)

Comment: As an "answerer" pointed out, in the title 7 ate 9 (7 8 9... Classic)... title/question mis-match.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 14):

Voila:

> 4 * ((8 + 7) * (9 + 4) - 10)

Solved by manually trying multiplying together pairs of added numbers then figuring out how to correct the error using the remaining terms.

Answer (score 10):

Using a small program, I've identified [272 expressions](https://pastebin.com/Fxqn29En), many of which are simply commutative transformations of each other.

Answer (score 6):

> (9*10+7-4)*8-4

Also solved by hand.

Answer (score 3):

> **((4*7)+9)*(8/4)*10**

*Solved in head* - *nostalgic* - I used to do this *(make up my own puzzles of this nature)* all the time when I was younger using the telephone numbers in the church bulletin in order to pass time.

-rC

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping to find a solution that kept the numbers in order, but I couldn't think of one.

> (9 * (8 + 4/4) - 7) * 10

My strategy:

> keep 10 to the side and use the rest of the numbers to hit 74, then multiply by 10

Answer (score 0):

I will answer to this question in steps:

> 1) Add numbers upto second last digit
>  2) Add numbers upto last digit
>  3) now add result of step 1 and step 2
>  4) multiply that result with last digit

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to see if it were possible without scrambling the numbers

> but the closest I could get was a disappointing:
> 744 = -4 - (-4 * 7) + (8 * 9 * 10)

Or If I resist the urge to pointlessly complicate:

> 744 = -4 + (4 * 7) + (8 * 9 * 10)

Comment: I think the double-negative can be simplified into just an addition?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Well.  Probably...  but I have a natural gift for complicating things that I don't want to waste! (edited)

Comment: You still need the `-` at the start though ;)

Comment: As long as unary negation is allowed: `4*( -4 + 7*( 8 + 9 + 10 ) ) = 740`

Comment: @Paulpro Simply awesome...  +1